# LFS 7.10 Stable 2nd pass of GCC fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to setup a [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) system, however I get an error while compiling GCC for the 2nd pass. I am sure I did all step before (I redid them multiple time), but each time, no matter if I write `make` or `make -jN` I get the same error :

```
In file included from ../../gcc/genconstants.c:28:0:
../../gcc/system.h:221:22: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or
directory  # include <algorithm>
```

How can I fix this ? Is it a package I didn't compile correctly ? I did a parallel make of libc, is that the problem ? This one didn't give me any error though.